# When travelling to Austria, do I need to prove that I haven't been in High-Risk Areas in the last 10 days and if yes - how?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, covid-19, austria, bulgarian-citizens

I will be visiting Austria next week and stay there for a couple of days. According to the [Official travel portal of Austria](https://www.austria.info/en/service-and-facts/coronavirus-information) residents of Germany do not need to show a negative COVID-19 test or commit to quarantine. I haven't been in a High-risk area in the last weeks so I am allowed to enter Austria, but as I am Bulgarian Citizen do I need to prove that I haven't been in Bulgaria or other high-risk countries in the last days? If yes - how can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've traveled by car from Italy to Austria recently and here's how their border control looks like:

- You roll up to the border officer
- They ask you where you've been and whether you have any COVID symptoms
- If you haven't been to any high risk countries they let you in, zero documentation required

Quite frankly I'm not sure how you would even be able to produce such documentation given that EU citizens don't get stamped at the border. So it's effectively an honor system.

Comment: Curious, was it the police (who does regular border control) or the military (who, at least at Schwechat, checks COVID-19 compliance separately)?

Comment: @Crazydre no idea, just some people in a uniform. They didn't wear military khakis, but I presume that's not the only outerwear available to the military.

Comment: Until I read the first sentence here, I kept seeing "Australia" for some reason :)

Comment: I haven't seen any border control while entering or leaving Austria. Probably because I drove some nice roads and therefore went through small check points.

Comment: @Dirty-flow I saw them at the tiny mountain border crossing ([here](https://goo.gl/maps/DCzKK47U8em5PDzu9)) from Italy to Austria. Its possible that they've been removed on the German border.

Comment: @JonathanReez The only COVID-19 document checks I know are still in operation are the military checks at Vienna airport

Answer (score 8):

Just checked this with the Austrian border policy section.

In case of doubt, you may be asked for proof of residence in Germany (not because residence in Germany is required, but to support your claim that you haven't been to a high-risk country).

This can be a *Meldebescheinigung* (if having lived in Germany for less than 5 years) or a *Bescheinigung des Daueraufenthalts* (if having lived in Germany for 5 years or more)